# Dockerfile run screen command while keeping it attached

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that I would like to run a script as its entrypoint.
The script contains a single command with a shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -S mc bash -c "java -jar paper-1.18.2-387.jar"
```

My dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:18-alpine
RUN apk --update add screen
WORKDIR /
COPY . ./

RUN apk add gcompat
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libgcompat.so.0

COPY run.sh /run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/run.sh"]

EXPOSE 25565
```

However, when I run the docker file the screen session that it should have attached is never executed. I have tried using the `/bin/bash` tag, but it tells me that it doesn't exist. I need this screen to be attached so that the docker image continues to run, and I am using screen so that I can have another session attach elsewhere.

How can I run this single command as my dockerfile entry point?

I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks!

Comment: Alpine images don't normally include bash.  Can you use `sh -c` in your script?  You also might remove the unnecessary `sh -c` wrapper from the Dockerfile (`CMD /run.sh` would have the same effect, `CMD ["/run.sh"]` would remove the shell wrapper entirely)  Could you ignore Screen here, run the Java application itself as the main container process, and look at its `docker logs` from outside Docker?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by modifying my script to look like so:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
screen -S myScreen sh -c "sh start.sh"
```

And adding a second script named `start.sh` that looks like

```bash
#!/bin/sh
java -jar paper-1.18.2-387.jar
```

And modifying my Dockerfile to look like:

```
FROM openjdk:18-alpine
RUN apk --update add screen
WORKDIR /
COPY . ./

RUN apk add gcompat
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libgcompat.so.0

COPY create-screen.sh /create-screen.sh
COPY start.sh /start.sh

CMD ["/create-screen.sh"]

EXPOSE 25565
```

Reconnecting to the screen involves running `screen -x` on the shell of the image. Since it is already attached by the CMD process, the window may look comically tiny because the headless docker process created it with a weird default size. This is an easy fix, you can look it up.